# Using Windows azure cloud service for making mobile and web application

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I am a newbie to Windows Azure platform.
  
    My team is developing a web and a mobile application and we are thinking of going with this platform. But I have few doubts taking that:

    My web and mobile application will access the same database, so is it possible to have a same cloud database in windows azure allowing both mobile and web application to access it 

    Few examples and references will help a lot.

Note: I have a request and reponse operations from both client and server, so its two way communication process for mobile and web app.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

We built a project recently that was built using webAPI on MVC 4.0. We built an Azure Cloud service project in Visual Studio 2012 ,and created a web role that hosted both webapi (REST based Services) and MVC web application.

To secure our API, we implemented a token based security mechanism over the WebAPIs for user authorization. We created two different Routes /Rest/API (to handle CRUD) and REST/RPC(to handle additional operations.

In all, we had following layers in the solution

MVC Web Project 
--API (APIControllers - REST + RPC)
--Controllers (MVC Controllers)
-- VIEWs
MVC Web ROle Project
-- Mapped to the MVC Project in the web
Repository
-- Repository classes for entities
Data Access
-- Data Access classes for each entity using DAPPER
Models
-- POCO Classes representing entiries

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually we are having iOS,Android as mobile and a Php web app. We are planning to deploy a cloud database and service layer (php back-end) on windows Azure and have mobile n web front end access them. Is it that we have to shift to asp.net for that instead of php?

Comment: azure api supports php.So it should not be an issue.

Comment: What I understood is fairly in a technical way , architecture wise, is it easy and flexible to have a common database n server side scripts between a web n mobile app?